# Libertarian "thought experiment" about planned economy

Tags: reference-request, political-philosophy, economics

I once stumbled upon a text from a libertarian (I believe it was a philosopher) setting out a thought experiment to show that even a planned economy run by "omniscient bureaucrats" would produce inferior results than a free market.

Sadly I have forgotten who wrote it and where to find it. Can you give me some suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Any chance you're talking about *The Road to Serfdom* by Friedrich Hayek?

I haven't read the above book in ages, but I did stumble across the following on an amazon review of a closely related book named *Individualism and Economic Order*, which is a collection of several essays:

> After dealing with the absurd notion of full information, Hayek turns
>   to three issues. First, Socialists once aimed at overcoming the
>   results of markets. Now they accept the results of market competition
>   as a standard to aim at. Second, an omniscient and omnipresent
>   dictator would also require omnipotence to plan an economy using their
>   omniscience. Even if they had omniscience, the central planners would
>   still have to work through an imperfect bureaucracy. So the notion of
>   omnipotence is absurd. We must look at the actual bureaucratic
>   problems that planners will face. Third, Perhaps, in a world of
>   unchanging data Socialist planners could arrive at efficient prices
>   for the means of production through trial and error. But, with
>   changing data, the plans of the authority will never match the
>   decisions of the 'man on the spot'. Hayek discusses incentive problems
>   and knowledge problems at length, and also mentions the potential for
>   abuse by concentrating power into the hands a few. This is the subject
>   of his book "The Road to Serfdom".

Given Hayek's economic views, it wouldn't be too surprising to come across an essay which supports the free market over planned economies.

Comment: Yes, this sounds very, very good. I remember this "not even omniscience and omnipresence would be enough, one would also need omnipotence". Very probably it was a passage taken out from this book, I'll try if I can find it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: No problem, good luck.